# Cron Job Issue on Once a Day

Tags: cron, centos6.5

I have two Cron Jobs running on CentOS.

- One Every 5 Mins Its working fine

  ```
  */5 * * * * curl "http://10.133.43.243/cron/aaa.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
  ```
- Another One Once a day

  ```
  0 0 * * * curl "http://10.133.43.243/cron/bbb.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
  ```

This Cron Not Working fine. But When I call this URL Directly its working fine.

I'm new to Centos Crontab comments .

Comment: Could you provide us with some more information. Cron sends emails with error information but you send your stuff to `/dev/null`. Mapbe send the `stdout` and `stderr` to a file with   `0 * * * curl "http://10.133.43.243/cron/bbb.php" > ~/logfile.txt 2> ~/errlogfile.txt`. This could help you out.

Comment: Hi @kvantour i found the issue . I Change server timezone but Didnt restart the system . so the cron files are executed based on the old timezone.